# Como utilizar elementos HTML dentro de SVG no Angular?

Tags: html, angular, svg

Estava utilizando SVG no Angular, quando precisei colocar elementos HTML dentro do mesmo. Então primeiro testei no w3schools. Imagem com o código e resultado esperado abaixo.

[image: Código e resultado no w3schools]

Então repliquei no Angular("xhtml:" nescessário). Imagem do código abaixo.

[image: Codigo no Angular]

O resultado no Angular não aparece o elemento HTML'select'. Mas se perceber no código do navegador o 'select' está presente. Imagem abaixo.

[image: Resultado do Angular]

O que falta para o elemento aparecer?

Comment: Amigo qual eh a sua intenção em usar um select dentro de um svg?

Comment: Construir um componente que tenha opção selecionáveis dentro dele. Não é para ser um retângulo na versão final, se não utilizaria uma <div>.